# JQuery popup $.post inner function do not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, popup

Please help me in my Javascript - $.post - popup script. I tried to debug the script below, but I found that it doesn't go inside the function(data)... What can be the problem? Thanks for replies.

Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#survey').dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 500,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
            Submit: function () {
                if ($("input[name='elso']:checked").val() !== undefined && $("input[name='masodik']:checked").val() !== undefined && $("input[name='harmadik']:checked").val() !== undefined && $("input[name='negyedik']:checked").val() !== undefined) {
                    setCookie('POPsurvey', 'POPsurvey', 30);
                    $.post("process_survey.php", $("#popup_survey").serialize(), alert("hsgh"),

                    function (data) {

                        if (data.db_check == 'fail') {
                            $("#error_message").html("<p>Adatbázisunk nem elérhető. Kérjük, próbálja meg újra.</p>");
                        } else {
                            $('#survey').dialog('close');
                            $('#survey_thanks').dialog('open');
                        }
                    }, "json");
                } else {
                    $("#error_message").html("<p>Kérjük, minden kérdésre adjon választ.</p>");
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
          $.post("process_survey.php", $("#popup_survey").serialize()).done( function (data) {

                    if (data.db_check == 'fail') {
                        $("#error_message").html("<p>Adatbázisunk nem elérhető. Kérjük, próbálja meg újra.</p>");
                    } else {
                        $('#survey').dialog('close');
                        $('#survey_thanks').dialog('open');
                    }
                });
```

Comment: `$.post("process_survey.php", $("#popup_survey").serialize())
     .always(function() {
         alert("finished");
     })` check it out if alert comes...if not then you are getting some error in console or the call is not getting completed

Comment: it killed javascript... and alert didnt came..how can I find out my console or call errors?

Comment: You open the console and go to the network tab in chrome and see the status of your call

Comment: when I submit the form, it calls process_survey.php, and status is 200, so it gets the message OK. But the php still not does the msql query (at network tab it says access denied)

Comment: "db_check":"fail" the response. But the calling function doesnt show any response (it should show error message).

Comment: Can you try $.cookie() instead of setcookie()

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
$('#survey').dialog({
    bgiframe: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 500,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: {
        Submit: function () {
            if ($("input[name='elso']:checked").val() !== undefined && $("input[name='masodik']:checked").val() !== undefined && $("input[name='harmadik']:checked").val() !== undefined && $("input[name='negyedik']:checked").val() !== undefined) {
                setCookie('POPsurvey', 'POPsurvey', 30);
                $.post("process_survey.php", $("#popup_survey").serialize(), 

                function (data) {

                    if (data.db_check == 'fail') {
                        $("#error_message").html("<p>Adatbázisunk nem elérhető. Kérjük, próbálja meg újra.</p>");
                    } else {
                        $('#survey').dialog('close');
                        $('#survey_thanks').dialog('open');
                    }
                }, "json");
            } else {
                $("#error_message").html("<p>Kérjük, minden kérdésre adjon választ.</p>");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

});

function (data) must be after serialize

Comment: yes, it was before... i made alert for testing. Still dont works without alert.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove that alert as the third parameter in the post function like this

```
$.post("process_survey.php", $("#popup_survey").serialize(),
 function (data) {
  if (data.db_check == 'fail') {
    $("#error_message").html("<p>Adatbázisunk nem elérhető. Kérjük, próbálja meg újra.</p>");
  } else {
    $('#survey').dialog('close');
    $('#survey_thanks').dialog('open');
  }
 }, "json");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your serialize
add this to your code and use serializeObject (not serialize)

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function(){
var o = {};
var a = this.serializeArray();
$.each(a, function() {
    if (o[this.name]) {
        if (!o[this.name].push) {
            o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
        }
        o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
    } else {
        o[this.name] = this.value || '';
    }
});
return o;
```

};

Comment: I add this to my code, and used $("#popup_survey").serializeObject(). It doesnt work, and doesnt refresh my form - shows the data selected before, even after page refresh.